# Database structure and associations for open-ended data and data types

Tags: database, cakephp, database-design, content-management-system

I'm trying to build a custom CMS tool (yes I know - ANOTHER CMS) where the users can create as many nested "nodes" as they want.

Example "Nodes":  Restaurants, People, Shoes, Continents ... anything.  Within each Node, there can be as many sub nodes as needed and so on and so forth.

While looking through Wordpress, Drupal... etc etc, I keep seeing tables like "taxonomy", and "terms".

This seems like a "normal" thing, but I can't wrap my head around how it should be done or how they're doing it.  I assume these tables are related to the overall structure and table relationships, but... searches online come up shy of explaining what's actually going on or how best I would go about designing my database for this kind of structure.

---

**Ideas I've had so far** (that obviously aren't flushed out or I wouldn't be here asking):

**1) Store known data types and bindModel():**
Create tables like `data_locations` and `data_texts` that would have fields respective of their data.  So - in the `data_locations` table, I'd have `city`, and `longitude`, and `address`.  And in the data_texts table, I'd have `title`, `subtitle`, `content`, `author`.

Then, each time they created a new "Node", they could pick what kind of data-types it should have, and I would use `bindModel()` to create the associations (I guess?).

This wouldn't be as flexible, but maybe easier to manage, and faster to run queries on...etc?  Dunno.

**2) Custom fields for each Node with single "data" table:**  Have a `data` table, and a `fields` table...  each node would haveMany `fields` - each with a type and maxLength...etc.  Then, in the admin, I'd list those fields, and each chunk of data `title`, `shoe_size`...etc would have a row in the `data` table that related to the node and to the field.

This one seems more like what I THINK the "taxonomy" thing is - but again, I really have no idea.

Comment: I'll give +50 bounty for the best answer

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also interested in some further explanation on this subject.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983137/saving-data-with-varying-keys-and-values

Answer (score 1):

Which database are you considering? Graph databases tend to be more natural for this kind of thing in my opinion.

In a relational database it is tricky. Nesting queries of arbitrary depth are not natural (but doable), dynamic schema are also unnatural (see 'EAV schemas' via google to see the arguments around that) and are very difficult to query well.

Have a look at neo4j. I think you can express your requirement directly and naturally.

Comment: EAV helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983137/saving-data-with-varying-keys-and-values/17983955#17983955