# Saving data with varying keys and values

Tags: cakephp, database-design, backbone.js, inline-editing, drupal-8

**What I want to do**

I want to have templates tied to a page that can have varying amounts and kinds of data within it.

So template a can have a list or just body content or a special layout.

I want part of this content to be editable from the frontend using create.js. So the page title, the body content, ect would all be editable and need to be saved somewhere (mysql) and somehow. I do not want the content edited in one big WYSIWYG editor.

**Similar Functionality but not quite**
Wordpress allows for tying custom data to a post via post meta.

Drupal does this by defining fields and tying them to nodes somehow.

I am using cakephp to build this site but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to save and retrieve this data in a simple understandable way.

I have tried searching for a solution but I don't really know exactly what I am asking is called.

So in summary I am using cake 2.3, create.js (which has backbone and underscore and VIE) to build pages that can be saved to a database but have varying amounts and styles of editable areas. These pages will be administered in the same environment they are displayed.

The goal here is to give the end user some editing without compromising the design. I am asking for good resources so I can research this subject further. Libraries or examples of this in the wild would be great.

Similar question. 
[Database structure and associations for open-ended data and data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911271/database-structure-and-associations-for-open-ended-data-and-data-types)

Comment: http://ycmi.med.yale.edu/nadkarni/eav_CR_contents.htm

Comment: Helpful for understanding EAV http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1

Comment: For Cakephp this looks really promising. http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/abalonepaul/2011/10/11/eav_behavior

Comment: I'm going to advise against copying Drupal design patterns because they are, for the most part, very terrible ideas.  The "fields" and "nodes" and "entities" concepts make a recipe for programmer hell.  A database class will effectively have taught you to avoid doing those things with a database.

Comment: I agree that relational is best where it makes sense, but the data I am saving doesn't have any structure and isn't related in a super consistent manner. It is actually per page and I don't want to have to maintain an extremely unweildy database table. I think EAV has its place and can be done well. See my answer for what I think to be a great solution. I will keep this updated with my findings.

Comment: Right, since you recognize EAV, I'm supposing you'll do fine :3 Good luck!

Comment: http://tonyandrews.blogspot.ca/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html -- the giant SQL query makes a great argument against EAV -- please, protect the sanity of "the next database minded guy" who has to deal with the legacy you're building up and avoid it, k? XD

Comment: Your tone is disrespectful and not very professional so that weighs in on considering your opinion. Furthermore, just because you site one negative about a method doesn't defunct its use. **Please propose a solution instead of being a critic.** I doubt you looked at the solution for cake since it doesn't require writing any sql.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34653/discussion-between-starlocke-and-kelvin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cakephp this looks to be an excellent solution.

http://debuggable.com/posts/unlimited-model-fields-expandable-behavior:48428c2e-9a88-47ec-ae8e-77a64834cda3

Updated version for cake 2.3

https://github.com/zeroasterisk/CakePHP-Expandable-Plugin/blob/master/Model/Behavior/ExpandableBehavior.php